# ASP.NET MVC Base Address changes when publishing to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I published an MVC4 app on IIS and my base adrress changed to `localhost/somevirtualdirectory/Home/Index`.

That works fine however when I click on a ActionLink ( tag) I'm being redirected to `localhost/someController/Action` and that fails since the `somevirtualdirectory` is missing in the url.

How can I set the the action will redirect to the baseadrress with the virtual directory?

Comment: What does your routing look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in your action link you have entered your URL hard coded starting with slash which will throw you to the parent directory and thus excluding the subdirectory. Use `Url.action` to form the URL which will include your sub-directory when you hit :

```
@Url.Action("Action_Name", "Controller_Name")
```

there is a difference. Html.ActionLink generates an  tag whereas Url.Action returns only an url.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

generates:

```
<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
```

notice this slash at the beginning of the href which will take you to the root .

```
and Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }) generates:

/somecontroller/someaction/123
```

Now when you click It will append it on the sub directory

Comment: I've used @Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller")